Is There any thread listening for a reply from the external resource?
I'm discovering reactive programming with Spring WebFlux and Netty. When we call some external service we make a request with WebClient, receive a publisher(Mono or Flux) and at the same moment release thread for doing some useful work with other client requests. So question tormenting me is: Is there any thread listening for a response from an external resource? How do we get a response if we don't block calling thread, who (which thread) controls response receiving and returning it to client?


the operating system is handing network traffic and notifies your application when there is data to be fetched. Your application is not listening on any ports.
